# Are there any modern big-endian or non IEEE-754 PCs, or smartphones?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, endianness, ieee-754

I'm working on a multiplayer game. In the communication between the server and the client, do I need to encode and decode floating point and integer numbers?

Can I assume, that almost all PCs and smartphones have IEEE-754 and little-endian integer format?

Comment: No, you shouldn't, unless you are tied to a specific hardware platform.

Comment: Is there any point in not doing it?

Comment: Just as one existing example, Google protocol buffers use little-endian IEEE-754 for floating-point types. Naturally, any protobuf implementation for a platform using a different format would need non-trivial encode/decode functions for those types, but this fact hasn't troubled Google :-)

Comment: Good for Google. So long as a server tries to match its format to the client, there will be a catch-me-if-you-can game where the client has to find out if the server has found out the endianess of the client architecture. This was never a problem as a local issue, but now it is. The sooner this nonsense is forced out, the better. Just as automobile gearbox shift and control pedal arrangements became standardised decades ago. Long live EBCDIC-compliant code: not!

Comment: Could you please provide one example of a modern PC or smartphone, which is only big-endian, or does not support IEEE-754? Because without it I can not even test it, if my code works there.

Comment: the Power PC can be run in either Endian mode and different OSs run it differently.  You might want to read this wiki page: `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC`.  Here is a quick excerpt: " OS/2 and Windows NT for PowerPC ran the processor in little-endian mode while Solaris, AIX and Linux ran in big endian."